# webpack doesn't output bundle file

Tags: webpack

Here is my folder structure:

```
config
 |--webpack.config.js
entry
 |--app.js
output
```

And here is my part of my `webpack.config.js` file content:

```
module.exports = {
    context: path.join(__dirname, '..'),
    entry: {
        app: './entry/app.js'
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve('.', 'output'),
        filename: '[name].bundle.js'
    },
```

When I run the webpack, no file output in the `output` folder. However, the terminal show no error, also the `app.bundle.js` seems already been ouputed.

```
Hash: 0d0e4e77f57e49724b60
Version: webpack 2.6.1
Time: 22416ms
        Asset    Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
app.bundle.js  389 kB       0  [emitted]  [big]  app
chunk    {0} app.bundle.js (app) 1.1 MB [entry] [rendered]
   [26] ./~/react/lib/React.js 3.34 kB {0} [built]
  [100] ./~/react/react.js 55 bytes {0} [built]
  [116] ./entry/app.js 465 bytes {0} [built]
  [117] (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 5.64 kB {0} [built]
  [124] ./~/events/events.js 8.45 kB {0} [built]
  [151] ./~/react-dom/index.js 58 bytes {0} [built]
  [262] ./~/strip-ansi/index.js 161 bytes {0} [built]
  [265] ./~/url/url.js 23.1 kB {0} [built]
  [267] (webpack)-dev-server/client/overlay.js 3.61 kB {0} [built]
  [268] (webpack)-dev-server/client/socket.js 872 bytes {0} [built]
  [269] (webpack)/hot/emitter.js 89 bytes {0} [built]
  [270] ./src/scripts/module_b_es6.js 128 bytes {0} [built]
  [271] ./src/scripts/react_components/head.jsx 2.32 kB {0} [built]
  [274] ./src/styles/style.css 911 bytes {0} [built]
  [275] multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./entry/app.js
0 bytes {0} [built]
     + 261 hidden modules
webpack: Compiled successfully.
```

So what's wrong with my code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're running `webpack-dev-server`, which compiles your bundle but does not write it to disk (it keeps it in memory).

You have to run `webpack` to get the output files.

```
webpack --config config/webpack.config.js
```

Comment: HI Micheal, can you specify what memory? My program is pulling it from disk when I use [tag:webpackdevmiddleware]. e.g. Lets say if I empty my bundle.js then my browser is actually pulling an empty file even when the server is on, it can watch file changes and successfully compiles it but the browser doesn't reflect them. Feels like the browser is not pulling it from any memory of any sort.